# When should one prefer "ON CREATE SET..." when using LOAD CSV

Tags: neo4j

I am importing a file of this form (where HAN_ID is unique):

```
"HAN_ID"|"Person_name_clean"|"Person_ctry_code"|"Matched"
"4"|"GESELLSCHAFT FUER NUCLEONIC & ELECT MBH"|"DE"|"0"
"5"|"IMPEX ESSEN VERTRIEB VON WERKZEUGEN GMBH"|"DE"|"0"
```

I see two ways to add the "name" label from "Person_name_clean" to each inventor, but am not sure with is more Cypher-ic and more performant. The difference is just in the last two lines.

```
// Option 1
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Inventor) ASSERT i.hanID IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///.../201609_HAN_NAME.txt" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (i:Inventor {hanID:row.HAN_ID,name:row.Person_name_clean});

//Option 2
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Inventor) ASSERT i.hanID IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///.../201609_HAN_NAME.txt" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (i:Inventor {hanID:row.HAN_ID})
ON CREATE SET i.name=row.Person_name_clean;
```

In addition to my specific case, I wonder if there are any general rules for which is preferred. Should it matter, the file contains several million inventors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: The `ON CREATE` clause can only be used after a `MERGE` clause. So, your second option should be:

```
//Option 2
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Inventor) ASSERT i.hanID IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///.../201609_HAN_NAME.txt" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (i:Inventor {hanID:row.HAN_ID})
ON CREATE SET i.name=row.Person_name_clean;
```

Option 2 should be used if you intend every `Inventor` to have a unique `hanID` AND the input file might contain `Inventor`s that already exist in your DB.

NOTE: to ensure that every `Inventor` in the DB will have a unique `hanID`, you should also create a uniqueness constraint:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Inventor) ASSERT i.hanID IS UNIQUE;
```

Comment: Thank you for the note on "ON CREATE".  I *think* that means that option 1 is the way to go, as I've followed the wise advice of importing my inventor nodes and their associated han_ID separately, allowing me to use "MATCH" rather than "MERGE" in this step, for greater speed.

Your help is much appreciated.